# cakephp REST api response is not json, its the full html page

Tags: php, json, cakephp, rest

I am using cakephp 2.1.1

And from what I read in the Doc. it lets you create REST api's pretty easily. (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html)

I cant figure out how to generate a JSON response, I am calling the api from objective c, and the response is the FULL HTML page.

I have this code in my controller

```
public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $message = 'Saved';
                //echo 'eyeys';

            } else {
                $message = 'Error';
            }

            $this->set('_serialize',$message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, all I did to enable REST in cakephp 2.1.1 is this  in the routes.phpRouter::mapResources('posts');
Router::parseExtensions();

Comment: You have to parse the json extension: `Router::parseExtensions('json')` then all requests ending in `.json` will automatically set the response type.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the response type

```
public function add() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type('json');
    $message = null;
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                $message = 'Saved';
            } else {
                $message = 'Error';
            }
        }        
   return json_encode($message);    
}
```

Also check out the official cakephp 2.0 [response documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakeresponse)

Comment: Note: if you parse the extension using `Router::parseExtensions('json')` you do not need to set the type, it will automatically be set for all requests with the `.json` extension.